# Local Coordinates Assignment

Tags: python, game-engine, coordinates

I have a modeled SCARA robot in blender, this is moved through the use of a sensor and a python program. The problem now is that my inverse kinematics solved angle does not coincide in run in blender. One possible solution is that assignment of local coordinates in the joints.

Is there someone here can help me out with this problem? It will help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about Blender or about a BGE game?

Comment: Yes about bge game

Answer (score 0):

Within the BGE the (parent)-local coordinates can be read and set via `KX_GameObject.localPosition`.

When you want to read/modify the orientaion you can use `KX_GameObject.localOrientation`. Be aware it is a matrix.

If there is no parent, the local coordinates match the world coordinates.